# Why is the id not updated using MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework

I'm trying out the recently released mongo package for entity framework [mongo driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/entity-framework/current/quick-start/). I added some code to insert a new entity into the database. unfortunately when I try to access the id, it always comes back as `000000000000000000000000`. I tried adding some attributes to the model class but this didn't work.

For the context I used the same context from the docs

```cs
internal class MflixDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; init; }
    public static MflixDbContext Create(IMongoDatabase database) =>
        new(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MflixDbContext>()
            .UseMongoDB(database.Client, database.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName)
            .Options);
    public MflixDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().ToCollection("movies");
    }
}
```

The model class is also the same, but I added some attributes.

```cs
internal class Movie
{
    [Key]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string rated { get; set; }
    public string plot { get; set; }
}
```

The code for the `Program` class (console app) is as follows

```cs
var client = new MongoClient("CONNECTIONSTRING");
var db = MflixDbContext.Create(client.GetDatabase("sample_mflix"));
var movie = db.Movies.First(m => m.title == "Back to the Future");

var test = new Movie()
{
    plot = "test",
    title = "test",
    rated = "test"
};
await db.Movies.AddAsync(test);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();

Console.WriteLine(test.plot + " with id " + test._id);
```

The output in the terminal is: test with id `000000000000000000000000`

I tried to add some attributes to the model class but it didn't make a difference. I was expecting the id field to be populated after the `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Thanks for reading and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the provider itself, it's example uses no attributes so it's possible that the attributes you are specifying are confusing their provider's identification of the PK? You could try removing all of the `[Bson*]` and `[Key]` attributes and see if that starts behaving as expected.

Otherwise, EF's default convention for expecting PKs to be identity columns is based on a naming convention of "Id", "{tablename}Id" or "{tablename}_Id".  You can nominate other column names using:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[BsonElement("_id")]
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
```

For columns with other relational DB providers that would work, as it tells EF not to send an ID value on insert. However normally if the DB is set up with an identity column, forgetting this attribute for a column name not recognized by convention would result in an error that the database cannot accept an explicit value for an identity column. (such as when using SQL Server)  for MongoDB, you would need to check how/if Mongo handles identity columns.

Comment: Looking at the mongodb ef docs quick reference, the ids are generated using the ObjectId.GenerateNewId() function. I guess this is the way to generate new the id beforehand. Couldn't it be possible for the id to already exists in the database?

Comment: If it is the provider or client code generating the ID then it is possible, though if that generation is something like a UUID/GUID then the chances of a duplicate are pretty insignificant. It is something that I handle via an exception/retry scenario rather than burdening  every insert scenario with a check that is 99.99995% unnecessary.